# Web Scraping app using Scrapy / Selenium generates Error: "ModuleNotFoundError 'selenium'"

Tags: selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

Good morning!

I have recently started learning Python and moved onto applying the little I know to create the monstrosity seen below.

In brief:
I am attempting to scrape SEC Edgar (https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/cik.htm) for CIK codes of companies which I want to study in more detail (for now just 1 company to see if it's the right approach).

To scrape the CIK-code, I created a scrapy spider, imported selenium and created 3 functions - 1st to insert "company name" in the input name, 2nd to activate the "submit" button and finally, a function to scrape the CIK code once the submit is activated and return item.

Apart from adding the item to items.py, I haven't changed the middlewares or settings.
For some reason, I am getting ModuleNotFoundError for 'selenium', although I have installed the packages and imported selenium & webdriver along with everything else.

I have tried to mess around with indentation and rephrased the code but achieved no improvement.

```
 import selenium
 from selenium import webdriver
 import scrapy
 from ..items import Sec1Item
 from scrapy import Selector


class SecSpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SEC_sp'
    start_urls = 
['http://https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/cik.htm/']


  def parse(self,response):
    company_name = 'INOGEN INC'
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata ={
        'company': company_name
    }, callback=self.start_requests())


  def start_requests(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(self.start_urls)
    while True:
        next_url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '.search-button'
        )
        try:
            self.parse(driver.page_source)
            next_url.click()
        except:
            break
    driver.close()

  def parse_page(self, response):
    items = Sec1Item()
    CIK_code = response.css('a::text').extract()
    items["CIK Code: "] = Sec1Item

    yield items
```

I seem not to be able to get over the import selenium error, hence I am not sure about the extent of needed adjustments to the remainder of my spider.

Error message:

```
"File/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/Scraper/SEC_1/SEC_1/spiders/SEC_sp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import selenium
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Thank you for any assistance and help!

Comment: pip install selenium

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did  both pip install and manual addition of selenium in my IDE library. For a change I am having some issues with WebDriver - "executable may have wrong permissions."
The main thing is , is the code above alright to do the task or is there some issue I am missing?
Thanks